# Give the minimum and the maximum number of edges in an undirected connected graph of n vertices?

Tags: graph, tree

would minimum be (n-1) edges?

I am unsure about maximum

Answer (score 8):

Yes.. The minimum number of edges for undirected connected graph is `(n-1)` edges. To see this, since the graph is connected then there must be a unique path from every vertex to every other vertex and removing any edge will make the graph disconnected.

For the maximum number of edges (assuming simple graphs), every vertex is connected to all other vertices which gives arise for `n(n-1)/2` edges (use handshaking lemma). Another way: look over K_n (the complete graph with n vertices) which has the maximum number of edges.

Comment: "removing any edge will make the graph disconnected". Why?

Answer (score 8):

**Claim: If there are N verticies, the Min is N-1 and the max is N*(N-1)/2**

Proof:

Consider an adjacency matrix, where the elements are either 1 (to indicate the presence of an edge) or 0 (to indicate the absence of an edge).  For a graph to be connected, there must be at least one "1" in each row of the upper triangle.

The **minimum** is achieved by only placing one 1 in each row of the upper triangle.  Now, if the adjacency matrix is N by N, the first row has N-1 elements in the upper triangle, the second has N-2 elements in the upper triangle, ..., and the last row has 0 elements in the upper triangle.  That is, there are N-1 total rows "with an upper triangle", each with only one 1.  Hence, the number of edges in N-1.

The **maximum** occurs if every element of the upper triangle has a one.  Now, the number of elements in the upper triangle of the whole matrix is

1 + 2 + ... + (N-2) + (N-1) = N*(N-1)/2.

For the last equality, recall your calculus courses' finite sums.  Please see the second formula here, and replace "m" with (N-1)": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Sums_of_powers

PS: I really wish I could use LaTeX on SO!